# How can I get all child elements of a Jetpack Compose view in Android using Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Android: How can I get all child elements of a jetpack compose view?

In case of xml i am able to find child view using these line of code.

```
public void getChild() {
    View v = getwindow().getdecorView().getrootView();
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup) v;

        for (int i = 0; i < g.getChildCount(); i++) {
            Log.d("find: ", g.getChildAt(i).getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

tried this but unable to get

as i run this after `androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView` view i am getting nothing.
Please suggest some solution if anyone can solve this.

Comment: What's the usecase?

Comment: You have no way to do it

Comment: @JanBína Hi,

I am building an application that will show all the child element attached to decoreview.

here is screenshots https://prnt.sc/nbvVwCGMRn8B

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh Hi,
Is there any documents that says we can't get child of compose ?